# Suggestions on how to speed up this python function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, cython, numba

Any suggestions on how to speed up this function?

```py
def smooth_surface(z,c):
    hph_arr_list = []
    for x in xrange(c,len(z)-(c+1)):
        new_arr = np.hstack(z[x-c:x+c])
        hph_arr_list.append(np.percentile(new_arr[((new_arr >= np.percentile(new_arr,15)) & (new_arr <= np.percentile(new_arr,85)))],99))
    return np.array(map(float,hph_arr_list))
```

The variable `z` has a length of ~15 million and `c` is value of window size `+` and `-`. The function is basically a sliding window that calculates a percentile value per iteration. Any help would be appreciated! `z` is an array of arrays (hence the `np.hstack`). Maybe any idea if numba would help with this. If so, how to implement?

Comment: ``xrange`` suggests this is code for Python2. Is this correct?

Comment: yes this is python 2. Sorry, should've added that

Comment: 2.7 to be exact

Comment: How big is the window size in practice? What is the average size of the sub-arrays in `z`?

Comment: I'd say on average the size is anywhere from 10-15

Comment: I'm using c=2 so it would be that average x 5 for the variable "new_arr"

Comment: @JérômeRichard Any ideas?

Comment: You will likely get some more useful results if you include a reproducible example in your question that also includes the time elapsed. This would mean adding input data, imports, and output data. Naively, a sliding window is likely something you can accelerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slow part of the computation appear to be the line `np.percentile(new_arr[((new_arr >= np.percentile(new_arr,15)) & (new_arr <= np.percentile(new_arr,85)))],99)`. This is due to the unexpectedly slow `np.percentile` on small arrays as well as the creation of several intermediate arrays.

Since `new_arr` is actually quite small, it is much faster to just sort it and make the interpolation yourself. Moreover, numba can also help to speed the computation up.

```py
@njit #Use @njit instead of @jit to increase speed
def filter(arr):
    arr = arr.copy() # This line can be removed to modify arr in-place
    arr.sort()
    lo = int(math.ceil(len(arr)*0.15))
    hi = int(len(arr)*0.85)
    interp = 0.99 * (hi - 1 - lo)
    interp = interp - int(interp)
    assert lo <= hi-2
    return arr[hi-2]* (1.0 - interp) + arr[hi-1] * interp
```

This code is 160 times faster with arrays of size 20 on my machine and should produce the same result.

Finally, you can speed up `smooth_surface` too by using automatic parallelization in numba (see [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html) for more information). Here is an untested prototype:

```py
@jit(parallel=True)
def smooth_surface(z,c):
    hph_arr = np.zeros(len(z)-(c+1)-c)
    for x in prange(c,len(z)-(c+1)):
        hph_arr[x-c] = filter(np.hstack(z[x-c:x+c]))
    return hph_arr
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I never even thought of just calculating it myself with a separate function. I will try this out in my code. Thanks again. This could save me hours (or more) in runtime

Comment: looks like I'm stuck without the "parallel" option and "prange" until I update to a later version of numba (currently have 0.33). Even without those 1 million iterations went from ~32 seconds to ~9.4 seconds. Thanks again!

Comment: For anyone seeing this...using @njit(fastmath=True) for the "filter" function helped speed up things even more. Should be mentioned that this was used for python 3.9 which is different than the original question (where python 2.7 was being used)